# iOS: willSelectRowAtIndexPath called on bottom of tableViewCell

Tags: ios

I have a custom UITableViewCell that has 2 buttons and a label on it. The problem is that willSelectRowAtIndexPath only gets called when I click right above the bottom of a cell.

I set User Interaction Enabled to true for the UITableViewCell. This allows the buttons I have in my cell to be clickable.

If I set it to false, I willSelectRowAtIndexPath gets called when I click anywhere in the cell but the buttons no longer work.

Please help!

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. If you "click" the button, you want the button to react, not the cell to be selected, right? So what is exactly is the problem? Is it that nothing happens when you "click" on the label that's bothering you? What exactly do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if the button can let that happen automatically when enabled. However we can let the cell know that it was selected.

```
- (IBAction)respondToClick:(id)sender {
    CustomTableViewCell *customCell = (CustomTableViewCell*)sender.superview;

    // You can signal the cell to select itself (will not send the delegate message)
    [customCell setSelected:YES animated:NO];

    // Alternately this can be done but I don't recommend
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [myTableView indexPathForCell:customCell];
    if ( myTableView.delegate && [myTableView.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:)] ) {
        [myTableView.delegate tableView:myTableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}
```